# Best practice when using calculations and joins

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a general quesiton about best practice when one has a SQL query, and you want to use joins/sub queries to calculate measures, which are then to be used in business rules.
I got taught two spesific ways, but as my career progresses and I met more people, they seem to prefer other methods of doing this.

below, I've written out 5 examples of what I'm referring to. Please note that they are not meant to be working SQL queries, simply examples to show the different methods.

```
--Example 1:  filtering in-line
select top 1
 from [Temp Data] base
 left join table1 t1    on base.key = t1.key
                        and t1.category = 1
                        and t1.status not in ('Voided', 'Deleted')

--Example 2: using where
select top 1
 from [Temp Data] base
 left join table1 t1    on base.key = t1.key
 where t1.category = 1
    and t1.status not in ('Voided', 'Deleted')


--Example 3: sub-query
select top 1
 from [Temp Data] base
 left join (select col1
                from table1 t1  
                where category = 1
                    and status not in ('Voided', 'Deleted')
                ) t1 on base.key = t1.key


--Example 4: if exists
select top 1
        ,case
            when exists (select col1
                            from table1 t1  
                            where category = 1
                                and status not in ('Voided', 'Deleted')
                                and base.key = t1.key
                        ) then 1
          else 0
         end
 from [Temp Data] base


 --Example 5: outer apply
 select top 1
 from [Temp Data] base
 outer apply (select col1
                from table1 t1  
                where category = 1
                    and status not in ('Voided', 'Deleted')
                    and base.key = t1.key
                ) t1
```

I'd like to hear people's opinions on the different methods.

Comment: Note that Example 2 using a `left outer join` and `where` clause is effectively an `inner join` because the right-hand table (`table1`) is referenced in the `where` clause without allowing for nulls (as mentioned by Dr. Linoff). As for which crafting the finest code, clarity is important for maintainability. The _execution plan_ will identify any performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 2):

The queries do different things.  So, you should choose the form that does what you want.

As an example, the second query turns the `left join` into an inner join.

The fourth one does no filtering at all, just setting a flag.

The first, third, and fifth are equivalent.  I think the first method would be the more "traditional" way for writing the query -- or at least I think more people would write it like that.  The subquery in (3) is superfluous (although no harm to performance).  And `cross apply` is not supported by all databases.

Comment: Ah yes good point about 4...  :)

thank you, that was a good answer on all 5.
much appreciated.

do you know about the performance of these different methods?